# Change ManipulationMode programmatically

Tags: c#, listview, windows-runtime, winrt-xaml, windows-phone-8.1

I'm trying to add some custom manipulation in a Windows Phone 8.1 WinRT app. Here's my scenario:

I have a ListView that scrolls vertically. When the user performs a Hold operation on an item in the ListView, I want to transfer manipulation events to a placeholder object that floats over everything else in the view. Then the user can drag this object to certain parts of the screen to perform an action.

The problem is when I have the ManipulationMode of the item set to "System, TranslateX, TranslateY" the Listview doesn't scroll ever (because the TranslateY blocks the Manipulation from reaching the ListView), but the dragging of the "item" works perfectly. If I set the ManipulationMode to "System, TranslateX" the scrolling works, but not the dragging of the item.

Is there a way to change the ManipulationMode of objects in the Holding event to block the listview from scrolling and to allow the dragging of the placeholder in X and Y directions.

Comment: Why do you need to transfer manipulation to another object? Would a solution that required a hold to select an item then a second gesture to move the item work?

Comment: Sort of. I got halfway there by toggling the ReorderMode of the listview. It mostly works now, except that it requires a "tug" horizontally to let me drag an item because one of the manipulation modes is TranslateX and not TranlateY. I can't use TranlateY because it would break scrolling.

Comment: did you look at the drag and drop samples from the msdn site? Did you set Listview's CanDragitems=True? Do the other containers on the page set AllowDrop=true? The reason for the questions is that if your scenerio is complex enough then I will share a very detailed solution but if it's simple drag and drop then you should start with the built in options.

Comment: I'm currently using the built in drag and drop. The only problem is that in order to "pick up" an item, you have to drag it horizontally to get it to enter free movement. You can't just drag vertically to pick it up. I don't know if this is by design with the built in drag-and-drop, or something caused by me setting the manipulation mode on each item to "System, TranslateX" for another interaction that can be performed when not in drag-and-drop mode.

Comment: Can you provide a code? I don't see how translateX is necessary with the drag and drop api

Comment: The TranslateX is necessary for a completely different interaction that happens when NOT in drag and drop mode. I have actions that happen when the user drags an item from side to side when in normal mode. But when in drag and drop mode, the need to be able to drag the items in any direction.